# Android : How to create new EditText onClickListener

Tags: android

I am new here, sorry if I am not so good in the explainаtion. ;)
I want to add and remove a dynamic EditText fields?

```
 private final View.OnClickListener addRowListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
           //HERE????
      };
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create the views

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
      TextView text = new TextView(yourActivity.this);
 };
```

If you have the views

```
 TextView TV1,TV2;
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
      if(TV1.getVisibility()==View.GONE)
           TV1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      else
           TV1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to add and remove your EditText from the Layout dynamically.

```
LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
```

To create New

EditText text=new EditText(this);
layout.addView(text);

to Remove

```
layout.removeView(text);
```

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  
  LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
  ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(FILL_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
  linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
  linearLayout.setOrientation(VERTICAL);
  
  linearLayout.addView(submitButton());
  linearLayout.addView(addRowButton());
  linearLayout.addView(deleteRowButton());
  setContentView(linearLayout);
 }
 
 int i = 0;

Comment: I can not say findViewById, it's dynamic...  I have to create another LinearLayout, right?    Thank You

Comment: 'private final View.OnClickListener addRowListener  = new View.OnClickListener() {
                
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                 EditText editText1 = new EditText(Sample.this);
                 
                 i++;
                 editText1.setId(Integer.valueOf((String.valueOf(i))));
                 editText1.setHint((String.valueOf(i)));
              editText1.setId(Integer.valueOf((String.valueOf(i))));
                 editTextList.add(editText1);
                 listView().addView(editText1);         }               };'

Comment: for further readability, Nayden, you are using the wrong comment quote key. rather than using the single quote 'comment', use  the " ` " symbol --- `comment`. Cheers.